# cannot setup PYTHONPATH environmental variable in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I tried to set up PYTHONPATH environmental variable in vscode in Mac, and it does not work. VScode version: Version: 1.78.1 (Universal), Mac os: 13.3.1 (a)
I followed the instruction:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable
In workspace setting.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#00ff00"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "ABC": "124"
    }
}
```

In the terminal, I type

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

and it returns:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.2/libexec/python/
```

I then set PYTHONPATH in user settint.json like this

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    }
}
```

I closed vs code and reopened, and type

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

and got same result.

I also set PYTHONPATH in .env right under workspace

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/{user_name}/gitlab/aws/dummy_project
```

it does not work either.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I found I define

```
export PYTHONPATH={some value}
```

in .bash_profile.  After I commenting this line,  setting in terminal.integrated.env.osx works.

Answer (score 0):

steps to configure the python path in vscode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8XwV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8XwV.png)

Then add python.exe path  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjubG.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).